# Steady State Temperature Profile of a Centrally Heated Pipe (or rod)

Tags: heat-conduction

This question is inspired by [a question from 'Robomaze'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699756/thermal-conduction-in-a-heated-body). The OP now seems to have lost interest in it but I still think it's an interesting issue.

I've cleaned up the original question and made it more concise.

---

A pipe (or rod) of total length $2L_2$ has a central section of length $2L_1$ that is heated constantly and uniformly at a rate of $q\,\mathrm{Wm^{-1}}$. The non-heated part loses heat through convection (but not radiation)

**What is the temperature profile ($T(x)$) of the pipe at steady state?**

[image: centrally heated pipe]

Answer (score 0):

1. Heated section:

The go-to equation here is Fourier's Heat Equation (with thermal load $q$):

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+q$$
Or:
$$T_t=\alpha T_{xx}+q\tag{1}$$
2. Non-heated sections:

These can be treated as convective heat losing fins, the derivation of which can [be found here](https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/propulsion/notes/node128.html). The resulting differential equation is (also steady state):
$$T''-\frac{Ph}{Ak}(T-T_{\infty})=0\tag{2}$$
Let's make a small transformation of dependent variable:
$$T-T_{\infty}=u$$

---

Because we're looking for steady state, so $u_t=0$, $(1)$ becomes:
$$\alpha u''(x)+q=0\tag{3}$$

$(3)$ integrates easily:
$$u'=-\frac{q}{\alpha}x+c_1$$
$$u=-\frac{q}{2\alpha}x^2+c_1 x+ c_2$$
Also, because the system's geometry is symmetric about $x=0$, that means the maximum  of $u$ must also be at $x=0$, so:
$$u'(0)=0 \Rightarrow c_1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow u(x)=-\frac{q}{2\alpha}x^2+ c_2$$
$(2)$, after the transformation of $T$ becomes:

$$u''-m^2u=0\tag{4}$$
$$\text{where }m^2=\frac{Ph}{Ak}$$
(For the definition of symbols please consult the link above)

$(4)$ solves to:
$$u(x)=c_3e^{mx}+c_4e^{-mx}$$
As a boundary condition, I choose 'no heat loss at the end-points', so:
$$u'(L_2)=0$$

Thus:
$$mc_3e^{mL_2}-mc_4e^{-mL_2}=0\tag{5}$$

The temperature profile must be differentiable so that the derivatives in $L_1$ must be equal:

$$mc_3e^{mL_1}-mc_4e^{-mL_1}=-\frac{q}{\alpha}L_1\tag{6}$$

$(5)$ and $(6)$ allow to determine $c_3$ and $c_4$.

Finally there can only be one value of $T_1$, so:

$$-\frac{q}{2\alpha}L_1^2+ c_2=c_3e^{mL_1}+c_4e^{-mL_1}\tag{7}$$

With knowledge of $c_3$ and $c_4$, $c_2$ can then be determined.